# How do I recursively aggregate values inside of a loop of JavaScript objects?

Tags: javascript, recursion, chart.js

I am having a tough time wrapping my head around trying to make a JavaScript function that transforms an object by looping through each of its Object's key's values and adding them up only if the Object key (which is a timestamp) is current to or greater than the preceding key.

To explain this visually, I am trying to turn the below graph (which looks not so visually appealing) to look more up-and-to-the-right, by aggregating each of the preceding day's values into the latest day.

[image]

---

## **Trying to turn this current object**:

```
var orderedTimeSeriesObject = {
    1573538400: { // Tue, 12 Nov 2019 06:00:00
        clicks: 14,
        signups: 20
    },
    1574316000: { // Thu, 21 Nov 2019 06:00:00
        clicks: 13,
        signups: 15
    },
    1574488800: { // Sat, 23 Nov 2019 06:00:00
        clicks: 0,
        signups: 0
    }
};
```

## Into this (the goal):

```
var orderedTimeSeriesObject = {
    1573538400: { // Tue, 12 Nov 2019 06:00:00
        clicks: 14,
        signups: 20
    },
    1574316000: { // Thu, 21 Nov 2019 06:00:00
        clicks: 27,
        signups: 35
    },
    1574488800: { // Sat, 23 Nov 2019 06:00:00
        clicks: 27,
        signups: 35
    }
};
```

---

Here is my current code:

```
var newOrderedTimeSeriesObject = {};

Object.keys(orderedTimeSeriesObject).forEach((timestamp) => { 
    newOrderedTimeSeriesObject[timestamp] = {};
    Object.keys(orderedTimeSeriesObject).forEach((timestampToCompare) => { 
        if (timestamp >= timestampToCompare) {
            Object.values(timestamp).forEach((metric) => { 
                const metricAggregated = metric + timestampToCompare[metric];
                newOrderedTimeSeriesObject[timestamp][metric] = metricAggregated;
            });
        }
    });
});

console.log(newOrderedTimeSeriesObject);
```

---

I've been banging my head on this for hours now and getting lost in the nested loops, and losing myself more when I try recursion. Is there something I am overlooking here -- is this even possible? Any guidance or help would be greatly appreciated.

## UPDATE:

Thanks to RK's answer, here's what I ended up going with:

```
let lastKey = 0;
let lastValue = null;
for (key in orderedTimeSeriesObject)
{
    if (lastKey < key && lastValue != null)
    {
        Object.keys(orderedTimeSeriesObject[key]).forEach((metric) =>
        {
            orderedTimeSeriesObject[key][metric] += lastValue[metric];
        });
    }
    lastKey = key;
    lastValue = orderedTimeSeriesObject[key];
}

console.log(orderedTimeSeriesObject);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this with `for..in` loop

```js
var orderedTimeSeriesObject = {
    1573538400: { // Tue, 12 Nov 2019 06:00:00
        clicks: 14,
        signups: 20
    },
    1574316000: { // Thu, 21 Nov 2019 06:00:00
        clicks: 13,
        signups: 15
    },
    1574488800: { // Sat, 23 Nov 2019 06:00:00
        clicks: 0,
        signups: 0
    }
};
var lastKey =0;
var lastValue ={clicks:0,signups:0};
for (key in orderedTimeSeriesObject){
   if(lastKey<key){
      orderedTimeSeriesObject[key].clicks+= lastValue.clicks;
      orderedTimeSeriesObject[key].signups+= lastValue.signups;
     lastValue = orderedTimeSeriesObject[key]; 
   }
   lastKey = key;
   
}

console.log(orderedTimeSeriesObject);
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you, this was super helpful. `lastKey` was the trick. I ended up modifying your code a bit to turn the `clicks` and `signups` to be dynamic. Thank you!